# How do I change the auto increment counter in MySQL from +1 to +43

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to change the auto increment counter in MySQL from +1 to +43.

For example my rows have Id = 1, 2, 3. 
But I don’t want the Id’s having +1 sequence.

I want them like 43, 86, 129

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=43
```

But this just changed the sequence to 43, 44, 45

Comment: Why? Id's are just id's. Those values don't mean anything.

Comment: i agree with @jarlh. Anyway the offset is managed at server level with the auto_increment_offset property. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) for reference

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the system variable [`auto_increment_offset`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) to the offset you want. But be careful using this solution since you change the offset for all tables (and `INSERT` commands). I don't recommend this solution, another column with a custom (calculated) ID would be a better solution:

```
SET @@session.auto_increment_offset = 43;

INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
```

You can also use the default auto increment (offset = 1) and using a calculation to get the custom increment:

```
SELECT id, id * 43 AS `custom_id`
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Mark S. Rasmussen's blog: https://improve.dk/working-with-identity-column-seed-and-increment-values/

**Changing the identity increment value**

Unfortunately there’s no easy way to change the increment value of an identity column. The only way to do so is to drop the identity column and add a new column with the new increment value. The following code will create a new temporary table, copy the data into it, recreate the original table with the correct increment value and then finally copy the data back using SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON.aspx) to insert explicit values into the identity column.

```
BEGIN TRAN

-- Create new temporary table to hold data while restructuring tblCars
CREATE TABLE tblCars_TMP
(
    CarID int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)

-- Insert tblCars data into tblCars_TMP
INSERT INTO tblCars_TMP SELECT * FROM tblCars

-- Drop original table
DROP TABLE tblCars

-- Create new tblCars table with correct identity values (1,1) in this case
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCars]
(
    [CarID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
)

-- Reinsert data into tblCars table
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblCars ON
INSERT INTO tblCars (CarID, Name) SELECT CarID, Name FROM tblCars_TMP
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblCars OFF

COMMIT
```